# ADB list of packages with more information

Tags: android, shell, package, adb, updates

I'm wondering is it possible to use ADB to get the list of all packages installed on device with information about last updates of each package. Maybe there is kind of file with updates history?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all packages and last update data you can use `adb shell dumpsys package`. It is very verbose, so it's likely that you have some filtering to do.

Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys